# get html input into a rails function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a piece of html like this:

```
    <div class="row well">
      <form method="POST">
        <ol id="velArea">
          <li>  Layer velocity: (m/s) <input type="text" name="source[]"> </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="button" value="Add another layer" name="velocity" onClick="addVel('velArea');">
      </form>
    </div>
```

and a javascript function that adds html to the area

```
    function addVel(area)
    {
      var field_area = document.getElementById(area);
      field_area.innerHTML += "<li>  Layer velocity: (m/s) <input type='text' name='velocity'> <a style='cursor:pointer;color:grey;' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);''>delete</a> </li>";
    }
```

I need to read the value of each input field in a rails function. And have no idea about how to do that. I've lost days going through active model in rails, thinking that was the way until I finally figured out that is better to keep the browser-related and server related things separated. So I learned a little javascript and made a few functions. Yes, I'm new to web development. I'm using rails 3.2.

The function that I want to uses the fields info is called by a button:

```
     <%= button_to "Run single inversion", {:action => "my_func", }, {:remote => true, :form => { "data-type" => "json" }, :class => "btn btn-primary"} %>
```

and the function on the controller is:

```
    def my_func
      render :nothing => true
      vel = params[:velocity]
      puts vel.class
      puts 'Hi'
    end
```

the output I get is

```
    NilClass
    Hi
```

so I'm clearly not passing the arguments right. I'm guessing I need to pass the velocity array in the post method when I use the button_to, but have no idea about how to do that.

Also, I'm need the value of the input, not anything database oriented so I cannot look it up using activeRecord properties.

Answer (score 1):

in your rails controller, you should be able to access a `params[:model_name]` when the javascript submits the form to whatever method you need it to go to. you can also access a `params[:id]` or `params[:firstname]`

i'm also a bit confused as to what you are doing with
`<input type='text'>  </input>`

that doesnt have a name attribute, which is needed by the model to identify it and associate its value with a column. it also isnt the proper way do an input.

`<input type="text" name="column_name"/>`

is closer to what you want

Comment: thanks! but I'm still missing how to pass the arguments. I added more info to the question. Tried using params[:name], but I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: There are a few fundamentals that you're missing here, but dont be discouraged! When you assign `params[:velocity]`  to `vel`, you are passing the VALUE of the velocity parameter, meaning whatever was typed into the input. You are NOT passing any other information about the velocity input element itself, so when you try to access vel.class, of course it will return nil. However, what happens when you type `puts vel`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your code is so complicated. But basically there are a few things, that are not the RailsWay. First, you should have a look to the [Rails Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). If you are using the conventions, you will receive a params hash like this:

```
params[:velocities][:velocity]
params[:velocities][:source]
```

The form tags would look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="velocities[velocity]" id="velocities_velocity" value="">
<input type="text" name="velocities[source]" id="velocities_source" value="">
```

In your above code you are expecting a value for vel. The resulting NilClass is because ther is nil in params[:velocity], so vel is nil. You should check the following:

```
puts params.inspect
```

Or have a look inside the log when running the Rails application.

And please recheck the name attributes of both the button and the input filed. They name attribute is both 'velocity'. If the button is the latter which is submitted, then the value of params[:velocity] is for sure empty ...

Comment: I was trying to use helpers, but the fields are not database related, and I just couldn't figure out how to use rails on them. In the nested forms examples there is info about how to add new forms, for example. But only when new items in a database are created. I cannot figure out more complex cases with only rails so I used javascript. The thing is that I have to be able to add or eliminate part of the forms.

Comment: basically what I need is: the user has to load a number of files, plus give a number of velocities. I have to use that info in a ruby function, which will call a C function on the server. I've made the forms using js, made a function using ruby, but cannot figure out how to make the call of the function.

Comment: ok - maybe this Railscast helps [http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised) ... I am not sure if it is for free ... Anyway - railscasts.com is a good place for finding basic Rails stuff.